# Delete word from a line in a text file

Tags: java, string, file, replace

I am trying to delete the words `alle 30 Min` in the lines of my timetable. Currently `30` and `Min` is being deleted but not the word `alle`. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Sample**

```
apple 05:05 05:35 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:35 08:05 17:05 17:35 18:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
chairalle 05:08 05:38 06:09 06:39 07:09 07:39 08:09 17:09 17:39 18:09 18:39 19:09 19:39
tablealle 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 alle 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
spoonalle 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 30 07:44 08:14  17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
cabelalle 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 17:17 17:47 Min 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
```

**exepted output without alle 30 Min:**

```
apple 05:05 05:35 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:35 08:05 17:05 17:35 18:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
chairalle 05:08 05:38 06:09 06:39 07:09 07:39 08:09 17:09 17:39 18:09 18:39 19:09 19:39
tablealle 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
spoonalle 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 07:44 08:14  17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
cabelalle 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 17:17 17:47 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
```

**Code:**

```
    Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(file)) {

    while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(" alle ")) {
            //Delete alle from the line.
            line.replace(" alle ", " ");
            String nextLine = scannerLines.nextLine();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\s");

            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(nextLine);
            while (m.find()) {
                value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());
                line.replace(m.group(), " ");

                String nextLine2 = scannerLines.nextLine();
                nextLine2.replace("Min", " ");
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
        writer.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell us what output you get and what you expect? As in, a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace(...)` method doesn't modify the original `String`, it returns a new modified `String`. You need to do something like this:

```
line = line.replace(" alle ", " ");
```

And here is a complete solution:

```
Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(file);
boolean alleFound = false;
boolean nrFound = false;
boolean minFound = false;
while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
    if (!alleFound && line.contains(" alle ")) {
        line = line.replace(" alle ", " ");
        alleFound = true;
    } else if (alleFound && !nrFound) {
        line = line.replaceFirst("\\s\\d\\d\\s", " ");
        nrFound = true;
    } else if (alleFound && nrFound && !minFound) {
        line = line.replace("Min", " ");
        minFound = true;
    }
    writer.println(line);
}
```

Comment: It works now thanks but why have it wored  for `30` and `Min`?

Comment: Those values are on the lines that you store in `nextLine` and `nextLine2`, you never add those line to the `writer`

Comment: @TheBook you have other errors in your code, I've edited my answer to include a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the **resulting string** back to line!

```
line = line.replace(" alle ", " ");
```

Refer to [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

**Working example:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestReplace {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        File inputFile = new File("Input.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("Output.txt");

        Scanner sc = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {       
            sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
            fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);

            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = sc.nextLine();                 
                str = str.replaceAll("\\s30\\s|\\salle\\s|\\sMin\\s", " ");                 
                fw.write(str + "\r\n");
            }

            sc.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
apple 05:05 05:35 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:35 08:05 17:05 17:35 18:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
chairalle 05:08 05:38 06:09 06:39 07:09 07:39 08:09 17:09 17:39 18:09 18:39 19:09 19:39
tablealle 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
spoonalle 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 07:44 08:14  17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
cabelalle 05:13 05:43 06:17 06:47 07:17 07:47 08:17 17:17 17:47 18:17 18:47 19:17 19:47
```

Comment: No sorry I am looking for `alle`

Comment: @TheBook Should `chairalle` become `chair`? Assuming that's what you want, remove the spaces surrounding `alle`

Comment: @Gosu Maybe it's a german data source. If you look at his sample data you'll find an 'alle'.

Comment: @Gosu: What? the substring `alle` in the word `chairalle` should not be deleted I just want to delete  alle in this format space+alle+space

Comment: @DirkLachowski and that `alle` would have been removed given his current code, I think he wants to remove `alle` from `chairalle`, `tablealle`..

Comment: @TheBook if it didn't work for alle (since you didn't assign the value back to the string), it shouldn't be working for '30' or 'Min' either.. seems weird but I think that's what you are missing

Answer (score 1):

You are having spaces before and after the word alle so remove that.

```
line.replace("alle", " ");
```

Comment: I tried it without space and it still does not work besides the substring alle in chair and other words should not be delleted therefor I am using the spaces in the if statement

Comment: @TheBook you didn't assign the resulting string from the replacement to your String variable, check my updated answer.